# running node filename with typescript files gives module not found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have `file1.js` which imports `file2.ts`. But when I run `node file1.js` I get an error

> Cannot find module "/path to file2" imported in "file1"

I have even tried converting `file1.js` to `file1.ts`, but then I get -

> TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

This is my tsconfig.json -

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "solid-js",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "baseUrl": "src"
},
"include": ["src"],
"references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

I have even tried adding `esm:true` to the tsconfig, but still no solution-

```
 "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
```

Please help find a solution.

Comment: Show your code where you're attempting the import